# localG get's something wrong with the IDs

Tags: r, geospatial

currently I am trying to do some spatial statistics. At the moment I am playing around with the local spatial statistic from Getis and Ord to indicate "hotspots" and "coldspots" of my dataset. gem$avginc is the average income for every municipality and gem.listw.20km is my spatial weights matrix.

```
abs <- localG(gem$avginc,gem.listw.20km,zero.policy=F)
```

First Question: As result I am getting abs as something from class "localG". Can anybody explain to me how I can transform this into a normal integer or data.frame? Or where is the advantage of this class?

So far, so good. Because I don't know another way round I transform this into a dataframe and plot it with ggplot.

```
a<-0
for(i in 1:2379) {a[i] <- abs[i]}
abs <- as.data.frame(a)
abs$id <- gem_codes$code
abs <- left_join(abs,coords,by=c("id"="id"))

ggplot(abs,aes(long,lat)) +
geom_polygon(aes(group=id,fill=a)) +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "darkred")
```

[localG Statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG08B.png)

As you can see from the plot, there are two municipalities who don't are at a position where they should be. It should be impossible to reach such a low (and therefore white-colored) value in the middle of dark red ones like the one in the plot. It look like something got mixed up, but I don't know how. I tried to use "spChk" argument in the localG function, but I didn't get it how to use it.

I hope anyone can help!

Comment: You might try to force the class change using the class function: `class(abs) <- "data.frame"`

Comment: Unfortunately , this doesn't work...

Comment: What is the message R returns?

Comment: R converts it into a data.frame, but it has zero observations in it.

Comment: Maybe a localG object is a list, which is more general than a data.frame. use the str() function to see what is contained in the object. There are probably more pieces of info than just the data. However, one of the items in the list will contain the data. you can use the $ sign to extract this item.

Comment: I am getting this as output:

Class 'localG'  atomic [1:2379] -1.179 -0.816 -0.66 -0.657 -1.092 ...
  ..- attr(*, "gstari")= logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language localG(x = var.list$vs, listw = gem.listw.dmax)

Comment: I found out that if i am using abs <- as.data.frame(matrix(abs)) i get the data.frame which I was looking for. But the ordering is still something I can't handle right, because the plot doesn't have the patterns which it should have.